# React testing library fails to check for disabled button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I'm using `react-hook-form` to control my form inputs (ChakraUI inputs) and disable Submit button in case an input is invalid

Since I have a multipage form I use `FormProvider` in parent component, changing validation schema depending on the current page

```
   const currentValidationSchema = validationSchema[activeStep];

    const methods = useForm({
        mode: 'all',
        defaultValues: DEFAULT_VALUES,
        resolver: yupResolver(currentValidationSchema),
    });
```

```
 <FormProvider {...methods}>
    <Box >{renderCurrentStep(activeStep)}</Box>
  </FormProvider>
```

And consume it with `useFormContext` in child component

```
    const {
        control,
        watch,
        getValues,
        clearErrors,
        setError,
        setValue,
        formState: { errors, isValid },
    } = useFormContext<IOrderProductFormData>();
```

```
    <Controller
        control={control}
        name="phoneNumber"
        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
            return (
                <InputMask
                    mask="999 99 999"
                    onChange={onChange}
                    maskChar=" "
                    value={value}
                >
                    {(inputProps: any) => (
                        <InputGroup variant="phone">
                            <InputLeftAddon>+1</InputLeftAddon>
                            <Input
                                type="tel"
                                ref={inputRef}
                                aria-label="phone-number"
                                data-testid="phone-number"
                                {...inputProps}
                            />
                        </InputGroup>
                    )}
                </InputMask>
            );
        }}
    />
```

The buttons gets disabled if the form does not pass validation but the current schema

```
<ArrowButton onClick={handleSendOtp} disabled={!isValid} />
```

The code works as expected but I'm struggling with writing unit tests to verify the button is indeed disabled when necessary.

```
describe('<PhoneNumber />', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await act(async () => {
            render(
                <WrapperForm>
                    <WrapperRouter>
                        <PhoneNumber {...props} />
                    </WrapperRouter>
                </WrapperForm>
            );
        });
    });



    describe('with valid input', () => {
        it('should show enabled button', async () => {
            const nextPageButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'chevron-right' });

            fireEvent.input(screen.getByTestId('phone-number'), {
                target: {
                    value: '22222222',
                },
            });

            expect(nextPageButton).not.toBeDisabled();
        });
    });

    describe('with invalid input', () => {
        it('should show disabled button', async () => {
            const nextPageButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'chevron-right' });

            fireEvent.input(screen.getByTestId('phone-number'), {
                target: {
                    value: '0',
                },
            });

            expect(nextPageButton).toBeDisabled();
        });
    });
});
```

The first step passes as it should with the valid value. The second one however fails with the following message

> ```
> expect(element).toBeDisabled()
>
> Received element is not disabled:
>   <button aria-label="chevron-right" class="chakra-button css-5c2176" name="chevron-right" type="button" />
> ```

For some reason, there is no `disabled` attribute on the button even though it works just fine from the UI. I would appreciate some help with that